# django restframework how to get the filtered queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is an example code. In the real environment there are a lot of query params.

views.py

```
class EavValueViewSet(PandasMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.EavValueSerializer
    queryset = models.EavValue.objects.all()
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('value',)
    filter_class = EavValueFilter
    ordering_fields = ('timestamp',)
    ordering = ('-timestamp',)
```

I searched the value , url is 
`http://localhost:8000/api/eav_value/?search=test` , and I want to something then return another Response.

How to get the filtered queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override `mixins.ListModelMixin` inside `viewsets.ModelViewSet` if you want get filtered queryset or try anything you want. In my example i only print it in console.

```
class EavValueViewSet(PandasMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.EavValueSerializer
    queryset = models.EavValue.objects.all()
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('value',)
    filter_class = EavValueFilter
    ordering_fields = ('timestamp',)
    ordering = ('-timestamp',)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
       # this is filtered queryset
       print(queryset)
       page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
       if page is not None:
           serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
           return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

       serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```